# NodePort Service not accessible from webapp inside minikube cluster, but from outside

Tags: elasticsearch, minikube

I have installed a kubernetes elasticsearch (v. 7.0.1) environment with a deployment and service using type NodePort running on minikube. When I hit `kubectl get services`, I get the relevant line:

```
elasticsearch                NodePort    10.101.5.85      <none>        9200:31066/TCP               27m
```

If I do

```
$curl http://$(minikube ip):31066
```

I get the usual elasticsearch page. If, however, I do

```
root@webapp-5489d8d6fd-2ml2w:/# curl http://localhost:9200
```

as root of a webapp on the same cluster, I get error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

Can anyone hint at the reason for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your elasticsearch service is `NodePort` type with ports `9200:31066/TCP`. 
It means that elasticsearch is using port `9200`, and `NodePort` is using `31066` port.

**1)** curl http://$(minikube ip):31066

MinikubeIP is your node ip. You can verify this using `$ kubectl describe node` So if you are use `port 31066` it connects correctly.

**2)** curl http://localhost:9200

You did not provide any information about other Deployments or pods so I assume you have Elasticsearch deployment with pod.

If you will execute `$ curl http://localhost:9200` in elasticsearch container it will work, because elasticsearch is running inside (local) this container.

If you want to curl from other (non elasticsearch pod) you have to use service which you have created with elasticsearch port.
`$ curl elasticsearch:9200` or `$ curl 10.101.5.85:9200`

From other containers you can also curl using `NodeIP` with `NodePort`
`$ curl $(minikube ip):31066` same like in point 1.

Usefull links:
https://gardener.cloud/050-tutorials/content/howto/service-access/

Hope it helps!